# Mouse over change image + link code. HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have this code I made, I don't understand why it wont work. Please help!

```
<a href="https://www.jspell.com/public-spell-checker.html">
    <img src="http://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/PetSmart/SV0401_CATEGORY_HERO-Dog-Cat-20160818?$SV0402$"
          onmouseover="http://cdn1-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/2011/01/file_22928_greater-swiss-mountain-dog-460x290.jpg'"
          onmouseout="this.src='http://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/PetSmart/SV0401_CATEGORY_HERO-Dog-Cat-20160818?$SV0402$"a>
```

I want it so when you hover over the image, it changes, and when you hover off, it changes back the original image.

Comment: Could you explain how do you want the link to work?

Comment: You aren't setting anything with onmouseover. You just have the url and don't tell it what to do with the url. You also have an 'a' at the end of the image tag, and don't close the a tag.

Comment: @Frost I would like it to change the page. (Not open new tab)

Comment: @JeremyE. is right. You need to change the `onmouseover`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="https://www.jspell.com/public-spell-checker.html">
<img 
 src="http://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/PetSmart/SV0401_CATEGORY_HERO-Dog-Cat-20160818?$SV0402$" 
 onmouseenter="this.src='http://cdn1-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/2011/01/file_22928_greater-swiss-mountain-dog-460x290.jpg'" 
 onmouseleave="this.src='http://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/PetSmart/SV0401_CATEGORY_HERO-Dog-Cat-20160818?$SV0402$'" />
</a>
```

Here you go, I replaced your triggers vy onmouseenter and onmouseleave and fixed your a tag.

Comment: Ok, but it's not changing the image back to the original image after you leave the mouse over.

Comment: Still not working for me, just changes the the second image.

Comment: You forgot to end the single quote.

Comment: I edited the answer, added a quote and used mouseenter and mouseleave instead of mousehover and mouseout.

Comment: Now it works! Thanks! I'll mark as answer when it'll let me. God bless.

Comment: You should close your image tag.

Answer (score -1):

onmouseover runs javascript code, you wanted to run a link as a code and that doesn't work. You have to set the src of the img elemnt with javascript inside the onmouseover. (See your onmouseout)

```
<a href="https://www.jspell.com/public-spell-checker.html"><img src="http://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/PetSmart/SV0401_CATEGORY_HERO-Dog-Cat-20160818?$SV0402$" onmouseover="this.src='http://cdn1-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/2011/01/file_22928_greater-swiss-mountain-dog-460x290.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='http://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/PetSmart/SV0401_CATEGORY_HERO-Dog-Cat-20160818?$SV0402$"</a>
```

Comment: `img` is an empty tag. It does not end with </img>. It simply ends like this -- `<img src="url" />`

Comment: Your `img` tag is broken.

Answer (score -1):

As is said, onmouseover onmouseout should be used to bind a javascript function to an event in order to manipulate the element. In this code you can modify the src property of the image.

By the way, the HTML it's not well built.

Check the following snippet:

```js
function movingMouseOverImage(el){
  el.src = "http://cdn1-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/2011/01/file_22928_greater-swiss-mountain-dog-460x290.jpg";
}

function mouseLeavesImage(el){
  el.src = "http://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/PetSmart/SV0401_CATEGORY_HERO-Dog-Cat-20160818?$SV0402$";
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.jspell.com/public-spell-checker.html">
    <img src="http://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/PetSmart/SV0401_CATEGORY_HERO-Dog-Cat-20160818?$SV0402$"
          onmouseover="movingMouseOverImage(this);"
          onmouseout="mouseLeavesImage(this);"></a>
```

Answer (score -2):

First thing noticed is `<img>` tag not closed properly. Also anchor tag needs to be closed as `</a>`.

```
<a href="https://www.jspell.com/public-spell-checker.html"><img src="http://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/PetSmart/SV0401_CATEGORY_HERO-Dog-Cat-20160818?$SV0402$" onmouseover="http://cdn1-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/2011/01/file_22928_greater-swiss-mountain-dog-460x290.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='http://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/PetSmart/SV0401_CATEGORY_HERO-Dog-Cat-20160818?$SV0402$"></a>
```

Comment: You're not solving OP's question - this should be commented, not answered.

Comment: @RichardYan sure I could but unfortunately I can not yet comment directly, I can only reply. :)

Comment: @Archana: So don't use answers. Work on your rep a little more so yuo can use comments, instead.

Comment: @Archana Alright then, but under this case it's better not to answer it, still.